# Notepad ++ How to remove all characters after a string

Tags: regex, expression, notepad++

I'm using regular expression in Notepad++, trying to delete everything after a particular word.

For example here is my text:

```
Bull01 blah blah
Bull02 Blah blah
Bull03 Blah
Bull04 Blah
Bull05 Blah
**
Bull300 Blah blah blah
```

etc..

Im trying to delete everything after the word `Bull`, so that my results ends up being just `Bull`. I thought it was as simple as searching for

```
Bull.*
```

but that deletes the whole row, *including* the word `Bull`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a look behind:

```
Search: (?<=Bull).*
Replace: <blank>
```

The handy thing about look arounds is that they assert a match without consuming anything, so you don't have to sully yourself with back references.

Answer (score 2):

You can search for `(Bull).*` and replace it with `$1` - but take care to **not** set dot matches \r and \n

Answer (score 0):

You may use a [*match reset operator* `\K`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/keep.html):

> `\K` keeps the text matched so far out of the overall regex match. `h\Kd` matches only the second `d` in `adhd`.

So, you match whatever you like (even quantified patterns like `\d+` or `[a-z]{7,}`), then insert `\K` and add `.+` to grab the rest of the line (1 or more characters other than line break chars):

```
Bull\K.+
```

Then all what remains is to use an empty string in the replacement pattern.

See the Notepad++ screenshot:

[image]